# cannot return all the properties of object in res.send

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have API controller method like below,

```
 let object = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "arrayKey": [
        {
           "arrKey": "arrValue",
            "arrKey1": 1
        }
     ]
 }
 export const foo = (req, res) => {
      object.arrayKey[0].arrKey2 = "somevalue";

      // this one is getting printed
      console.log("full pointer", object.arrayKey[0].arrKey2);

      // this one is gettig printed apart from arrKey2
      console.log("doc", JSON.stringify(object));

      // and the response below is coming correct
      // but arrKey2 is missing or undefined
      return res.status(200).send(object);
}
```

Here the object is returned value from mongoose.Schema. Can anyone help me why arrKey2 is getting printed when I point it fully, but why not getting printed or utilized while sending the response

Comment: You have a typo. `arrkey` !== `arraykey`

Comment: ...and `cosole.log`instead of `console.log`.

Comment: Thanks for typos, corrected the question

Comment: Still, `arrayKey` is not the same as `arraykey`. It's important to fix all the typos because in this case, they may be the problem

Comment: Corrected, however I just recreated the scene. Can you tell me possible solution for this kind of problem

Comment: I don't understand the problem now. After fixing the typos, your code works: https://repl.it/repls/MetallicUnsungAxis

Comment: @AkshayIjantkar, did you restart the application after making the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use something like the code below:

```
return res.json(200, object);
```

My guess is that express isn't doing a cloneDeep on the object.  JSON.stringify does the clone deep.  Hope this helps.